# How to match two filtered sheets in excel

Tags: excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogzmz.png)
Hai friends, 
how to match a two sheets values in excel as i mentioned in the image. Please help me & Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try the formula in `Sheet 3`,

Before that you should have the data in `columns A and B` in `sheet 3`

Enter the formula in `Column C` of `sheet 3`,

`=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$B$10,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0),2)`

and drag below. Let me know if it works.